# Github Workflow Error: Failed to download action 'https://api.github.com/'. Error: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception

Tags: github, automation, github-actions, workflow

Unable to download github action - tj-actions/changed-files@v23.1

```
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Test changed-files
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # OR "2" -> To retrieve the preceding commit.

      - name: Get changed file
        id: changed-files
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v23.1

      - name: List all changed files
        run: |
          for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}; do
            echo "$file was changed"
          done
```

I'm getting error as:

Warning: Failed to download action 'https://api.github.com/repos/tj-actions/changed-files/tarball/34a865a2b221bd60ec0d4c071f5e7a66ffdac88a'. Error: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Warning: Back off 26.677 seconds before retry.
Warning: Failed to download action 'https://api.github.com/repos/tj-actions/changed-files/tarball/34a865a2b221bd60ec0d4c071f5e7a66ffdac88a'. Error: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Warning: Back off 21.73 seconds before retry.
Error: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.